# Replacement ford fiesta radiator has extra hose

Tags: ford, radiator, fiesta, radiator-overflow

I own a ford fiesta mk6 car. I recently bought a replacement radiator. Unfortunately I think its for an older model or different variant (ST150?)

Is it possible to use the new radiator in my old setup if I remove and block the pipe marked in lime green in **Figure 2**. I'm not quite sure what it does.

For clarity the radiator setup that I have is **Figure 1** the new radiator with an extra hose is **Figure 2**.

Thank you for your time

### **Figure 1:**

[image]

### **Figure 2:**

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'm not sure, because the recovery tank is different as well (three vs two outlets). I mean, the whole system looks completely different in how its routed. The new radiator (in Fig 2) has four outlets on it, versus the two in Fig 1 as well ... If I were you, I'd look to get the correct radiator.

Comment: Hi Paulster2, thanks for messaging. The new radiator has the same hose configuration as the old one with the additional small outlet (marked green).

I'm not sure what the extra little outlet is or does to be honest. Does it prevent air bubbles at the top of the radiator? Add a small amount of cold water to the hot end of the radiator?

Cheers

Comment: That looks to be an addition ie factory change design to help reduce bleeding problems. Either get the other tank or change the rad... But would the other tank fit since the pipes change position?

Comment: What is the model year and the nation of sale?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What you've been sent is the radiator for the diesel variant  - as opposed to what appears to be the 1.25l Zetec petrol engine in your first diagram.

You're correct in that the "main" radiator connections are the same between the two (Despite the confusing placement of the lower hose on the second diagram it is the same hose and hooks up in the same place as on the first one)

The small "extra" connection on it is an overflow pipe back to the expansion tank, in *theory* if you were to block it off then the radiator *might* "just work" - **however** the internals of the radiator are going to be designed on the basis that coolant should be able to flow out of that outlet. So you're going to have to be very, very confident in buttoning that up pretty tight or you'll have Fun with Coolant Leaks!*

Honestly I'd be sending it back and asking them to send you the right one.

*No actual fun included.

Comment: Thank you for you answer and for clarifying what the extra connection was.
I think I'll take your advice and avoid the fun coolant leaks :)